# Set bits using node-redis with a custom offset

Tags: node.js, redis

I am having a bit of an issue figuring out the API. How can I go about using the API to send a request to Redis to execute something such as "bitfield somebf SET i4 #0 5"? i.e., set the first 4 bits at offset 0 to a 5 (0101). Currently, I execute setbit() 4 times setting the bits manually, which is rather inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet of code that you are looking for is:

```js
await client.bitField('key', [{
  operation: 'SET',
  encoding: 'i4',
  offset: '#0',
  value: 5
}])
```

The various commands and their arguments for Node Redis are not terribly well documented. My personal life hack for when I need to figure one of the more complex ones out—which happens quite a bit—is to take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/master/packages/client/lib/commands) for the tests.